# heat map-like plot does not show the correct color

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe `df` with some values from this list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']`, but sometimes not all values appear in `df`, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c'],['b','c','e'],['a', 'e', 'f']])
```

I plot a heat map-like plot of `df` with the code below:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [['a','b','c'],['b','c','e'],['a', 'e', 'f']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

value = ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i','j']

value_to_int = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(value)}

n = len(value_to_int)     

#color for value
cmap = ['#b3e6b3', '#66cc66', '#2d862d', '#ffc299','#ff944d', '#ff6600','#ccddff','#99bbff','#4d88ff','#0044cc']

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5, 5)) 
ax = sns.heatmap(df.replace(value_to_int), cmap=cmap,  linewidths = 0.005, annot = False) 

#add value into plot
text = df.to_numpy()
for r in range(text.shape[0]):
    for c in range(text.shape[1]):
        ax.text(c+0.5,r+0.5, text[r,c], 
                va='center',ha='center')

# modify colorbar:
colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar 
r = colorbar.vmax - colorbar.vmin 
colorbar.set_ticks([colorbar.vmin + r / n * (0.5 + i) for i in range(n)])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(list(value_to_int.keys()))          

plt.show()
```

but the plot I got is not correct, the colors do not fit with the values, for example `'c'` should be dark green, on the heat map is however orange, etc.

[image]

how can I modify my code that it show me the correct colors? thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: add `vmin=0, vmax=9` to the `sns.heatmap` call. It has something to do with the scale of the graph and the colorbar.